# Sql Query For Search Not Working

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to check whether a word is exists in the table **tblword** or not.Here I am giving an input through ckeditor to check the presence of word in table. And on linkbutton i.e **lblviewentry** click and if the input word is exists in table.
The label i.e label2 text should be "found" if word is not present in table label text should be "not found". Now the problem is that even if I enter the word that is exists in table label2 text is "not found" .Below is what I have done.

Html used

```
<div>
 <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtentrytitle" CssClass="textbox2" placeholder="Entry 
 Title..." Width="100%" runat="server" Height="104px"></asp:TextBox>
 <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditorControl2" BasePath="~/ckkeditor" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
</div>
<div>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lblviewentry" CssClass="btn btn-primary shadow1" runat="server" OnClick="lblviewentry_Click"> <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></span></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

Code behind linkbutton:

```
DataTable dt = OJC.GetBadWord(CKEditorControl2.Text);
    if (dt.Rows.Count>0)
    {
        Label2.Text="Found"

    }
    else
    {
        Label2.Text="Not Found"

    }
```

Method Used

```
   public DataTable GetBadWord(string Word)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString);
    string sql = "select *from tblword where Word=@Word";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Word", Word);       
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;

}
```

Comment: r u able to query the data from sqlserver using the query?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let me clear one point that in your sql query you are comparing word with CKEditor's Text

```
select *from tblword where Word=@Word
```

Here `@Word` is whole text of CKEditor i.e it may be single word or multiple lines right. In that situation your sql will not work as expected. Instead I will suggest you to search your column value in given CKEditor Text i.e

```
select *from tblword where @Word like '%'+Word+'%'
```

Here @Word can be multiple line you should have set proper length for it.

Comment: But if he is looking for the word "one" and he has "everyone" he will get "Found".

Comment: Yes you are right @OffirPe'er but `one` is not bad word right ??  OP wants to search bad words right??

Answer (score 0):

Actual you are using CKEditer for filter record , which get data with html code 
check here [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1253f6c1-7a1a-4465-a0b1-7c87dbfa7a76/how-to-recieve-the-source-html-data-from-ckeditor-in-c?forum=csharp)
so make sure your are filtering same record as ckediter get

put like condition in your select command

```
Select *from tblword where Word like '%'+ @Word + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Trim the word:

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Word", Word.Trim());
2. Use 'like' in your query:

   string sql = "select * from tblword where Word like % @Word %";

Answer (score 0):

Uh, you are not opening the connection.  That code should be failing.
Never mind - fill will open the connection.

The answer is you you don't really have that word in the table
Run in the command in SSMS

For speed and ease you are better off just reading all the word into a HashSet once

Comment: `SqlDataAdapter`'s `Fill` method implicitly opens connection right??

Answer (score 0):

I think you need split the text for search each word, not? 
or concat them and change the query from `WHERE` to `WHERE IN(W1, ...)`.

It also seems that you need not the results, but just to know if the value is in the table or not. So I would like

```
public bool IsBadWord(string Word)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString);
    string sql = "select top 1 * from tblword where Word=@Word";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Word");

    foreach (var element in Word.Split())
    {
        cmd.Parameters[0].Value = element;
        if(cmd.ExecuteScalar()!=null)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think this Answer it better then the selected one.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this
 sql = "select * from tblword where Word like % @Word %";